# Pseudo Random Function vs Pseudo Random Generator

Tags: random

Hi all I am referring PBKDF2, I could not understand what exactly this Pseudo-Random Dunction.
What is the difference between the Pseudo-Random Function and Pseudo-Random Generator?

Answer (score 0):

1)in personal opinion ,Pseudo-Random Function is a likewise true function that can replace random function to simulate the exponential numbers from true random functions set ,for example 2^2n.In Pseudo-Random Function user just uses a seed (k) as key which will be calculated with input x to have a random result. The method is likewise to choose a function randomly from one function set.

2)Normally speaking to Pseudo-Random Function, one property is the advantage between probability of choosing pseudorandom function and probability of true random function is negligible. Then people can think they can choose the pseudorandom function to replace random function.

3)In true random function people must choose some function as random function but the territory or the amount of the whole functions set is too large which can not be stored in computer or written by human. So we choose pseudorandom function as a smart way.